# Insert multiple row using select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 'class' and 'class1'.

class:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| name | classid | rollnum |
+------+---------+---------+
| ram  | 10      | 1       |
| ram  | 10      | 2       |
| ram  | 20      | 1       |
| ram  | 20      | 2       |
| ram  | 20      | 3       |
+------+---------+---------+
```

Now I want to perform the below given query:

```
insert into class1 (name1,classid1,rollnum1) values((select name from class where name='ram' and classid='10'),(select classid from class where name='ram' and classid='10'),(select rollnum from class where name='ram' and classid='10'));
```

So that 'class1' table looks like below:

```
+-------+----------+----------+------+
| name1 | classid1 | rollnum1 | add1 |
+-------+----------+----------+------+
| ram   | 10       | 1        | NULL |
| ram   | 10       | 2        | NULL |
+-------+----------+----------+------+
```

But the above query gives me the below error:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `VALUES` use one `SELECT` statement:

```
insert into class1 (name1,classid1,rollnum1) 
select name,classid,rollnum 
from class 
where name='ram' and classid='10'
```